# How to determine if scrolling a UITableView was done by tapping the index?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, indexing

I want to determine when the index (transparent alphabet) along the side of a `UITableView` is tapped.  To be more specific, I have a sectioned `UITableView` that has an index, and said index does the right thing, but when the `UITableView's` `-scrollViewDidScroll` method is called, I want to be able to determine if said scrolling was the result of the user tapping the index, vs. dragging or swiping the table view itself. If anyone has ideas on how to do this, i'd love to hear about them :-)

Regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

You could override touchesBegan to monitor the location of any touch event that precedes scrollViewDidScroll.